# URL Pattern in node entity reference

Tags: entities, uri, path-aliases

I have a content type A, which contains an entity reference field. That field references a content type B.
I have create automatic URL paths for both content types.

When I create a new node of type A, in the same page I can add a node of type B since it's referenced. The issue is URL alias for node type B won't create. If I want that pattern for B to work I have to create that node independently (not 'inside' of node type A) or create it 'inside' A and after edit it. It will work in that case, but I'd like not to have to edit every node of type B, and just create them once and have its URL working.

I have found similar threads but nothing exactly like this. I'd appreciate any help.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you use D7?
Do you use the Inline Entity Form module to add a new referenced node of type B? (https://www.drupal.org/project/inline_entity_form). I just tested the following workflow with the Inline Entity Form and Pathauto, and path aliases were successfully created for both nodes (type A and referenced type B):

- enable inline_entity_form and pathauto modules
- create the Entity Reference field on content type A that references content type B; select 'Inline entity form - Single value' as a widget type
- create patterns for both content types in admin/config/search/path/patterns (ex: for A - 'news/[node:title]'; for B - 'people/[node:title]')
- create a new node of type A, within it create a node of type B
- both nodes should have the correct aliases